# Why I cant add field to scala implicit class?

Tags: scala

Why you can not add a field to the implicit class?

for example the below code does not store the originalName field

```
object Implicit1 {

  implicit class AI1(c: Class[_]) {
    private var originalName = ""

    def setOriginalName(str: String) = originalName = str

    def getOriginalName=originalName
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An implicit class is a class that can be implicitly invoked as a wrapper for your class (in this case an instance of `Class`).  It absolutely can have a `var`; your code works fine in that sense.

The problem is that you have no way to get an instance of `AI1`.  So you create it, load up the `var`, and then throw it away.  It's not part of the original `c: Class[_]` instance; there's no monkey-patching going on here.  It just saves you typing `(new AI1(c)).whicheverMethodYouPutOnAI1`.

And if you did have a way to get an `AI1`, you wouldn't be able to get `c` again as you've written it.  `AI1` is not a proxy for `Class[_]`, it just holds an instance of it.  And right now your getter and setter don't add anything over just exposing the var.  So you perhaps meant something like

```
implicit class AI1(val underlying: Class[_]) {
  var originalName = ""
  def hasName = this
}
```

Now you can do things like

```
val named = "fish".getClass.hasName
named.originalName = "salmon"
println(s"${named.originalName} ${named.underlying}")
```

Comment: Why I can call a function in the wrapped class using implicit class but I cant store a value in it?

Comment: When I add the variable to the parent object `Implicit1`, it works correctly

Comment: You can't store it because _you don't keep the implicit class you created_!  And putting it in the companion is even worse!  That is exactly one variable that is shared between everything in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As Rex Kerr mentioned, the implicit class will be created every time when need. Hence you will get a new  instance of the implicit class every time, the value stored in the field has lost.

```
scala> val clz = "str".getClass
clz: Class[_ <: String] = class java.lang.String

scala> val impA: AT1 = clz
impA: Imp.AT1 = Imp$AT1@2d96543c

scala> val impB: AT1 = clz
impB: Imp.AT1 = Imp$AT1@7a560583

scala> impA == impB
res2: Boolean = false
```

Here is a workaround:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Imp {
   object AT1 {
     val clzBuffer = collection.mutable.Buffer[Class[_]]()
     val strBuffer = collection.mutable.Buffer[String]()
     def setName(clz: Class[_], name: String): Unit = {
       val ind = clzBuffer indexWhere (_ eq clz)
       if(ind == -1) {
         clzBuffer += clz
         strBuffer += name
       }
       else {
         strBuffer(ind) = name
       }
     }
     def getName(clz: Class[_]): String = {
       val ind = clzBuffer indexWhere (_ eq clz)
       if(ind == -1) "" else strBuffer(ind)
     }
   }

   implicit class AT1(c: Class[_]) {
     def originalName: String = AT1.getName(c)
     def originalName_=(name: String) = AT1.setName(c, name)
   }
} 

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Imp

scala> import Imp._
import Imp._

scala> val clz = "str".getClass
clz: Class[_ <: String] = class java.lang.String

scala> clz.originalName
res0: String = ""

scala> clz.originalName = "IamHere"
clz.originalName: String = IamHere

scala> clz.originalName
res1: String = IamHere
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing and abstracting a bit I use the following approach:

```
implicit class class_extension(val class_to_extend: class_to_extend) {
   import class_extension._
   private val fields = class_extension_fields_map.getOrElseUpdate(class_to_extend, class_extension_fields(default_value_1, default_value_2))

   def a = fields.a
   def a_=(value: Int) = fields.a = value
   def b = fields.b
   def b_=(value: Int) = fields.b = value
}
object class_extension {
   private case class class_extension_fields(var a: Int, var b: Boolean)
   private val class_extension_fields_map = new HashMap[class_to_extend, class_extension_fields]
}
```

This basically allows to “extend” classes in a certain context, e.g. adding fields to the – all – nodes of a graph for applying a certain algorithm.